# Native memory tracking reports unrealistic reserved heap size

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm, cgroups

Running my app in a container (adoptopenjdk11.0.13:debian) with 1g memory limit and maxrampercentage of 50

NMT reports shows this:

```
Total: reserved=17180391287KB, committed=817523KB
                 Java Heap (reserved=17179869184KB, committed=557056KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=17179869184KB, committed=557056KB)
```

'cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes' shows 104857600 as expected

How exactly does JVM calculate available memory if not by looking at cgroups limits?

Comment: Are you using ZGC? It's purposely reserves a huge amount of address space in order to use extra bits in the pointers ([colored pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926652/the-java-zgc-garbage-collector-uses-a-lot-of-memory/62934057#62934057)). It's OK to have that much "reserved" memory. The reservation of address space costs nothing.

Comment: @apangin Indeed, ZGC is the difference - the numbers are back to normal with G1

thanks for clearing this up