# Springboot 3 application crashes without any exception print in the logs

Tags: java, linux, debugging, gdb

We migrated our springboot application to springboot 3 with JDK 17.
We are seeing that the application is crashing without any error print in the logs.

If there is some `OutOfMemory` exception, I think some core dumps and hs_err files will be created on linux. We don't see any files created.

We have a script which starts the application if it finds it not running. So now the application is continuously restarting without any errors.

we only see the below logs

```
2023-10-20 12:38:38,043 ERROR c.m.c.v.s.i.SubscriberQueryRequestHandler [Scheduler-task-12] subQueryLst.size():0
2023-10-20 12:38:44,104 INFO o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [main] Starting Application v0.0.1 using Java 17.0.8 with PID 58021 (/opt/dist/WebController/cms-service-0.0.1.war started by cms in /)
2023-10-20 12:38:44,114 DEBUG o.s.b.StartupInfoLogger [main] Running with Spring Boot v3.1.4, Spring v6.0.12
2023-10-20 12:38:44,115 INFO o.s.b.SpringApplication [main] No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-20 12:38:49,470 DEBUG c.m.c.v.u.LoggingAspect [main] com.mavenir.cms.JasyptEncryptionConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0|Entered method : passwordEncryptor
2023-10-20 12:38:49,470 DEBUG c.m.c.v.u.LoggingAspect [main] com.mavenir.cms.JasyptEncryptionConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0|passwordEncryptor arguments are : []
```

We added this jvm argument while starting the application `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` but its not creating any dump files.

When I run `top` command, I see CPU spiking to `300%`+
please help
in `/var/log/messages` I see the below log, what does it mean?

```
Oct 23 07:00:34 CMSNFV-P_9_0_14_A kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0-1,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/psmon.service,task=java,pid=34091,uid=1006
Oct 23 07:00:34 CMSNFV-P_9_0_14_A kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 34091 (java) total-vm:315588020kB, anon-rss:570068kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:4624624kB, UID:1006 pgtables:13160kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Comment: Are you sure that your app crashes? It may simply close itself.

Comment: i can see that it's started and running, and then I see the Startup log again. It is starting again because of my script. I don't see any exceptions before it prints the startup log.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a bit difficult to diagnose.

If you stumbled into a crash you could enable the **OS core dump support** as follow:

```
# Become root...

ulimit -c unlimited
echo "/root/core-dumps" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern

# Restart the application (as NON root) and wait for crashing, then...

java -jar <your-war-file>

gdb /usr/bin/java /root/core-dumps/dump-file
```

If this solution will not work it maybe simply an unexpected application exit, so you can discover what it was doing at the exit event by:

```
strace -o my-app-trace.log java -jar <your-war-file>
```

Comment: is this a script?  should I start my application with this script?

Comment: They are commands not scripts.

Comment: my springboot application is a war file, should I run `gdb cms-service-0.0.1.war /root/core-dumps/dump-file`? this did not work, I get error `cms-service-0.0.1.war": not in executable format: File format not recognized`

Comment: I edit the post for better clarity...

Comment: i think its some memory related issue, in /var/log/messages, I see some OOM issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using ZGC in the java arguments, ZGC collector uses a lot of memory. Due to this Out of Memory killer in linux was killing the java process. I replaced ZGC with ParallelGC and it is working fine.

[The Java ZGC garbage collector USES a lot of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926652/the-java-zgc-garbage-collector-uses-a-lot-of-memory) This post throws some light on ZGc.